# Exception when using an enum member in parameterized test class with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, robolectric

I have a parameterized test class with an enum member as parameter.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B
}
```

This is the significant part of the test class:

```
@ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            {MyEnum.A}
    });
}

public MyTestClass(MyEnum value) {
}
```

When running the tests, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

If I change the constructor to

```
public MyTestClass(Object value) {
    MyEnum x = (MyEnum)value;
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.MyEnum cannot be cast to com.test.MyEnum
```

Can anybody tell me whats going on there? Especially the second case seems totally strange. I'm mainly a C# developer, so maybe this is special case in Java?
If I use other data types like Integer it works fine.

Thanks for helping!

Edit: The enum has actually 8 members, I just changed it here. Also, the constructor has more than one parameter, I just simplified the example. The type of value is correctly com.test.MyEnum

Edit2: The ParameterizedRobolectricTestRunner is the problem. If I use the (standard) Parameterized TestRunner, everything works fine. In this special case it is ok, since I don't test UI. But when testing UI, the problem would still occur.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {{MyEnum.A}});` returns an `List<Object[]>`, right? What class is `value` when you run in debug with a breakpoint at the cast?

Comment: it might that since you have just a single array an `MyEnum[]` is being passed to the constructor. Try adding a second case of `MyEnum.B`. Did you copy the error or type it? Did you miss the `L` array marking?

Comment: FYI, if you only have one parameter, generally Theories are the easier way to do this. Parameters are better when you want to explicitly pair values (either multiple inputs or input and expected output).

Comment: Did you ever make it work with Robolectric? There is a lot more to Android than the UI!

Answer (score 1):

That Class cast exception is quite strange. However, the following code ran for me:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamTest {

  MyEnum expected;

  public enum MyEnum{A,B}

  // Each parameter should be placed as an argument here
  // Every time runner triggers, it will pass the arguments
  public ParamTest(MyEnum expected) {
    this.expected = expected;
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { MyEnum.A },
        { MyEnum.B },
    });
  }

  // This test will run 2 times
  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    System.out.println("Enum is : " + expected);
    assertEquals(expected, expected);
  }
}
```

It prints:

> Enum is : A 
>  Enum is : B

Comment: You care returning a `Collection<MyEnum[]>`. This does not satisfy the contract of `@Parameters`. If you post an example that working using JUnit @Parameterized, that would be helpful.

Comment: Ahh missed that point. I have replaced my answer with the full working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like below. It's a little bit cleaner.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamTest {

  public enum MyEnum{A,B}

  @Parameterized.Parameter public MyEnum expected;

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static MyEnum[] data() {
    return MyEnum.values();
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
    System.out.println("Enum is : " + expected);
    assertEquals(expected, expected);
  }
}
```